# Не устанавливается библиотека PIL

Tags: python, pil

Не могу установить библиотеку PIL. Как её установить? Вот что выдаёт:

```
Collecting PIL
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PIL
```

Comment: `pip install pillow`, пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8f27b7807258a63fa2da1254647bf4245cf2c67c/pil_pillow__examples/blur/main.py#L7

Comment: Существует Pillow, поэтому PIL давно не нужен

Comment: Даже не смотря на существование pillow - они в своих мануалах призывают использовать import PIL